# VUEX does not find a mutation but it is defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm working with **VUEX** and everything was fine until I registered a new mutation "shipping" since every time I commit it tells me: **unknown mutation type: shipping**. But I do not understand the reason since the previous mutations work correctly.

This is my code:

**mutations**:

```
export function removeAllProducts (state){
    state.cart = []
}

export function shipping(state, cost){
    state.cart.shipping = cost;
};
```

**Component**:

**Template**:

```
<input type="number" name="cost" :value="shippingCost" @input="updateCost">
```

**Scripts:**

```
computed: {
   ...mapState( 'cart', ['cart'] ),
   ...mapGetters('cart', ['totalItems', 'totalCost', 'shippingCost']),
    shippingCost:{
      get(){ return this.$store.getters.shippingCost; },
    } 
},



     methods: {
     ...mapMutations('cart', ['addProductToCart', 'subtractProductToCart', 'removeProductFromCart', 'removeAllProducts', 'shipping' ]),
     ...mapMutations('routes', ['addRoute']),

      updateCost (e) {
        this.$store.commit('shipping', e.target.value)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might call your mutation wrong. If this line is correct:

```
...mapMutations('cart', ['addProductToCart', 'subtractProductToCart', 'removeProductFromCart', 'removeAllProducts', 'shipping' ])
```

Then the function `updateCost` should be:

```
  updateCost (e) {
    this.$store.commit('cart/shipping', e.target.value)
  }
```

if in your module you did set [namespacing](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) to true. Or the function can be

```
  updateCost (e) {
    this.shipping(e.target.value)
  }
```

since you already use `mapMutations` to map `shipping` to your component.

Comment: Thank you. With your recommendations I no longer have errors but nothing happens in the state either. In mutations.js within the function shipping (state, cost) I indicate the following: state.cart.shipping = cost; but it does not do anything: /

Comment: @OscarDev before continuing, I need to point out that your mutations has some conflicts. In mutation method `removeAllProducts`, you set `state.cart=[]`, but in `shipping`, you want to update `state.cart.shipping`, which clearly doesn't make sense if `cart` is an array. At least one of those 2 mutations must be wrong, or even both.

Comment: the removeAllProducts works has no problem, I inserted it only to be understood that I was already working correctly with VUEX

Comment: To find out, you can try to put `console.log` into your mutation to see if your mutation is called or not, and after update, how the state looks like. But that part is irrelevant to your original question, so if you need help, please create another question. I will not update my answer.

Comment: removeAllProducts I use when I want to empty the cart

Comment: Yes, I have created another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437537/mutation-does-not-update-the-store-in-vuex?noredirect=1#comment99469674_56437537  Thanks!