# Mutation does not update the store in VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Working with VUEX I am trying to update the store but I do not achieve it, I do not understand the reason since I only want to enter a numerical data without any complications.In the mutation enter messages by console and I receive them successfully but nothing happens in the state of cart.

This is my code:

**Mutations.js**

```
export function shipping(state, cost) {
    state.cart.shipping = cost;
    console.log(cost);
    console.log('hello from mutation');
}
```

**Template:**

```
<input type="number" name="cost" :value="shippingCost" @input="updateCost">
```

**Methods**

```
...mapMutations('cart', ['addProductToCart', 'subtractProductToCart', 'removeProductFromCart', 'removeAllProducts', 'shipping' ]),

    updateCost(event) {
      this.$store.commit('cart/shipping', event.target.value)
    },
```

**Computed**

```
computed: {
   ...mapState( 'cart', ['cart'] ),
   ...mapGetters('cart', ['totalItems', 'totalCost']),
   ...mapGetters('cart', ['shippingCost']),

  shippingCost() {
    return this.$store.getters.shippingCost;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to print value in html like `{{ cart.shipping }}`. what is showing? old value everytime?

Comment: Thanks friend but nothing shows.

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to do that: state.cart.shipping = cost; without a push on array.

Comment: Yes it is possible. you can do like that. 
If it showing nothing then your store `state` is not mapped well.

Comment: I have done a test with a push of an object or setting all the contents of the cart to the received value and it works well, but it does not work anymore when I pass the data only: /

Comment: Can you please provide any sample link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194411/discussion-between-hardik-and-oscardev).

Answer (score 1):

Solved, we must use VUEX as an object to be able to access more elements:

**Very Important**

```
const namespaced = true;  //important!!

export default {
    namespaced,
    state,
    mutations
}
```

**State:**

```
export default {
    cart: {
        products: [], 
        shipping : ''
    }
}
```

And enter your data in this way:

```
computed: {
   ...mapState( 'cart', ['cart', 'products', 'shipping'] ),
```

Regards

Comment: Is there any official document there for this? I assume it should still work if it is not an javascript object.

Comment: Hello friend, I did not find anything official in fact my solution was thinking that in the state we declared an array type property then I thought now declaring it with an object inside and it worked. Then I did not know how to get access to the object in the mapState because I kept saying it as ... mapState ('cart', ['cart']), and tried things like 'cart / products',' cart ', [' cart / producs'] without success until googling I found 'cart', ['cart', 'products'] and I realized that several same went through this problem.